# How can I reload a popup on the success branch of an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a popup with fields which should be filled in and after I hit save, I want to reload the content of the popup.

I want to do this by giving the reload command in the succes function of the ajax call. So far I tried

```
window.location.reload();
```

and

```
document.getElementById('#idOfThePopupContent').location.reload();
```

but nothing seems to work.  How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If it's inside a FORM tag then use reset button.

If it's not then you have to do it manually using JS or jquery.
1. empty the values of text,area fields,
2. remove checked,selected attributes from checkboxes,radio,select tags.

If you are using a single page type application with MVC, then re-render the view itself.